# How can I use Pandas column to parse textfrom the web?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pandas

I've used the map function on a dataframe column of postcodes to create a new Series of tuples which I can then manipulate into a new dataframe.

```
def scrape_data(series_data):
    #A bit of code to create the URL goes here

    r = requests.get(url)
    root_content = r.content
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(root_content)
    
    address = root.cssselect(".lr_results ul")
    for place in address:
        address_property = place.cssselect("li a")[0].text
        house_type = place.cssselect("li")[1].text
        house_sell_price = place.cssselect("li")[2].text
        house_sell_date = place.cssselect("li")[3].text
        return address_property, house_type, house_sell_price, house_sell_date

df = postcode_subset['Postcode'].map(scrape_data)
```

While it works where there is only one property on a results page, it fails to create a tuple for multiple properties.

What I'd like to be able to do is iterate through a series of pages and then add that content to a dataframe. I know that Pandas can convert nested dicts into dataframes, but really struggling to make it work. I've tried to use the answers at [How to make a nested dictionary and dynamically append data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789279/how-to-make-a-nested-dictionary-and-dynamically-append-data) but I'm getting lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your function only returns for the first `place` in `address` (usually in python you would `yield` (rather than `return`) to retrieve all the results as a generator.

When subsequently doing an apply/map, you'll usually want the function to return a Series...

However, I think you just want to return the following DataFrame:

```
return pd.DataFrame([{'address_ property': place.cssselect("li a")[0].text,
                      'house_type': place.cssselect("li")[1].text,
                      'house_sell_price': place.cssselect("li")[2].text,
                      'house_sell_date': place.cssselect("li")[3].text}
                          for place in address],
                    index=address)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll give it a go. I'm still very green to Python and its data structures although finding Pandas is definitely worth the effort to learn in my work. (Also thank you for tidying up my code)

Comment: That returned - SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument - Not quite sure where to put the parentheses, though.

Comment: @elksie5000 whoops! corrected by making it a list comprehension (sorry I had done this on my test).

Comment: That's brilliant - and super fast with your help. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code work, I eventually reworked Andy Hayden's solution to:

```
listed = []
    for place in address:
        results = [{'postcode':postcode_bit,'address_ property': place.cssselect("li a")[0].text,
                  'house_type': place.cssselect("li")[1].text,
                  'house_sell_price': place.cssselect("li")[2].text,
                  'house_sell_date': place.cssselect("li")[3].text}]

        listed.extend(results)
    return listed
```

At least I understand a bit more about how Python data structures work now.